# How to return Iterator with generic Item type from function

Tags: rust

I have a function like that:

```
fn factorials_iter() -> impl Iterator<Item = u64> {
    std::iter::once(1).chain((1..).scan(1, |acc, x| {
        *acc *= x;
        Some(*acc)
    }))
}
```

and instead of returning Item = u64. I would rather want to return something like impl Iterator<Item = T>. How to do that?

I tried to write this:

```
fn factorials_iter<T>() -> impl Iterator<Item = T> {
    std::iter::once(1).chain((1..).scan(1, |acc, x| {
        *acc *= x;
        Some(*acc)
    }))
}
```

but it fails with error

```
 expected `Chain<Once<{integer}>, Scan<RangeFrom<{integer}>, {integer}, [closure@main.rs:54:44]>>` to be an iterator that yields `T`, but it yields `{integer}`
```

Comment: Do you want the iterator to produce two ones at first? e.g. `1, 1, 2, 6, 24, ...`? If not, then  `(1..).scan(...)` would do

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: it expects an iterator that iterates returning the generic T to be returned, but it instead finds an iterator that iterates returning an integer. You need to change the definition of `factorials_iter` to return the proper type. What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this? What generic values do you expect to pass in for `T`? Just integers, or any type at all?

Comment: @MikaVatanen Yes. The idea of this function was to produce the collection of factorials starting from 0!, 1!, 2!... Calculation of 0! was tricky, I was able to do that only with conditional control type of expression like if, match, so I just put 1 as the first value in iterator

Comment: @AndersEvensen I wanted to delay the choice of the type to the caller. I was thinking of calling this function like that: factorials_iter::<u64>() with primitive type or newly created type let's call it BigInteger factorials_iter::<BigInteger>(). Im fine with narrowing/specyfing the type bound, and even based on the error message I was looking for a trait "Integer" to make function definition looks: fn factorials_iter<T: Integer>() then I was looking for something similar to c++ concepts to set requirement and narrow the type bound, but couldn't find that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to use the `num_traits` crate to request number-like operations from `T`, i.e. construction of `One` and `PrimInt` for multiplication and addition. You'll need to replace `1..` range with a full invocation of `std::iter::successors()`. The result could look like this:

```
use num_traits::{One, PrimInt};

fn factorials_iter<T: One + PrimInt + Copy>() -> impl Iterator<Item = T> {
    let range = std::iter::successors(Some(T::one()), |n| Some(*n + T::one()));
    std::iter::once(T::one()).chain(range.scan(T::one(), |acc, x| {
        *acc = *acc * x;
        Some(*acc)
    }))
}
```

You can test it with a larger type:

```
fn main() {
    println!(
        "{:?}",
        factorials_iter::<u128>().take(25).collect::<Vec<_>>()
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could pass in the type through function parameter:

```rust
#![feature(step_trait)]

fn factorials_iter<T: std::iter::Step + std::ops::MulAssign + Copy>(
    initial: T,
) -> impl Iterator<Item = T> {
    std::iter::once(initial).chain((initial..).scan(initial, |acc, x| {
        *acc *= x;
        Some(*acc)
    }))
}
```

Comment: And you can use `num_traits::One::one()` to obviate the need of passing the initial value. [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fd5d5b7774073593a8eea9db700307e8)

Comment: Note that this code requires nightly Rust, i.e. it doesn't work on stable and uses a feature whose design might change before stabilization (or be retracted altogether).